# Center tabular in align

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, align

I'm trying to place a tabular containing some values for x and y inside an align statement.

```
\begin{align*}
    0 &= 0 \\
    \begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|}
        %table content
    \end{tabular} \\
    1 &= 1
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Since this isn't really pretty I'd appreciate to center the table.

Or is there a way so one could share the alignment over 2 aligns?

Thanks in Advance for any suggestions :)

Edit: I tried grouping the tabular together with a `\centering` command, which did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `amsmath` offers an `\intertext{...}` command to set complete lines inbetween equations. `\centering` such "intertext" material could lead to the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    0 &= 0 
    \intertext{\centering%
                \begin{tabular} {|c|c|r|}
                \hline
                  x  &  0  &  1 \\
                \hline
                  y  &  0  & -1 \\
                \hline
                \end{tabular}
              }
    1 &= 1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

with the output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not a scaleable solution if you got many tabbles, but you can manually align the equations by padding it with \hspace

```
\begin{align*}
    0 &= 2 + 5 - 7\\
    &\hspace{-20pt}\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        a & b & c \\
        \hline
        c & d & e \\
        \hline
        f & g & h \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}\\
    5 + 7 - 11 &= 1
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. You can make do with a bit less manual intervention, by using `align*` as in the OP's original code, and adding `&\hspace{-15pt}` (or some other suitable length) right before `\begin{tabular}`.